Is "UN law" a thing?
A certain book features a (former) US city which for story reasons is "administered" by the UN and thus falls under their laws, rather than US/state law.
Now, in context of the fictional work, I'm sure this can be made to work, but I am curious whether there is such a thing in real life as "UN law", and would it be sufficient to keep a city functional? It seems that "UN law" would be equivalent to "international law", but I wonder if that is comprehensive enough that a functional town/city of ~60k people could function without additional laws. Also, does any place like this exist in real life?
Questions

Does "the law of the United Nations" reasonably correspond to any real legal system?
If so, what laws would these be?
Are there any real life places that are under such jurisdiction?


What book is this?

I don't think there's anything like this. UN resolutions address actiivity by member states, not individual people/companies.

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/

Clarity: book title missing, as that would inform lots of unsaid things, such as if Our normal undeestanding of laws applies at all.

The reason I am not asking on WB or including the book title is because I'm not asking about its fictional universe. I want to know whether there is such a thing as "UN law" in the real world, and if so, what it is.

The UN also doesn't have a legal system with which to enforce laws. There's something called United Nations Police, but it's more of a military unit used to support peacekeeping missions, not like a typical police force.

@Barmar, in the story, an agency is created for that purpose. AFAICT from the (good!) Answers here, the system of laws would also have been specially created, with no way of knowing what those laws might be that isn't extremely speculative. This answers my Question; thanks, all!

So this fictional UN has taken on more powers than the real UN, so that "UN laws" makes sense.

@Barmar, well... by international agreement, an agency is formed under UN control to govern the city. This doesn't seem entirely unprecedented based on some of the Answers (n.b. the VIC), but yes, it also seems to be the case that enough "scope creep" happened that there is no real world basis from which to guess what the laws are in the story. Since I consider this satisfactorily answered, I'll be merciful on y'all's curiosity  ...the story is Wen Spencer's (excellent) Elfhome series, in which Pittsburgh finds itself unexpectedly in another dimension.

International law deals with the interaction of states, it doesn't have anything to say on municipial administration. There are various declarations, treaties, etc, that could reasonably be called "UN law", but these do at the most lay out general guiding principles for how states should treat their citizens, or handle very specicialized parts of life with a highly transnational component. Again, nothing on how to run a city.
The UN has never directly administered a city, nor is it meant to do so. As such, it doesn't have a standard municipial code it would apply it such a situation. Historically, the League of Nations did find itself with territority that needed adminstratration after WW1, but it handed it to specific countries to deal with it instead.
So in reality there isn't really anything coming close to the fictional situation described here.

Just so I'm clear... is e.g. the UN building under New York / US law? There are no regions/territories (e.g. international waters, Antarctica) for which the UN is empowered to set laws?

How was Gdansk administered? It was technically directly under the league of nations, wasn't it? (wiki )

@Matthew There is a treaty regarding the UN headquarters which is more like a foreign military base agreement. NY and U.S. law apply there subject to specific limitations established in the treaty. https://treaties.un.org/doc/Publication/UNTS/Volume%2011/volume-11-I-147-English.pdf "There are no regions/territories (e.g. international waters, Antarctica) for which the UN is empowered to set laws?" Correct. Each of these non-state areas is individually governed by multi-lateral treaties (Law of the Sea Treaty, Antarctica Treaties, space treaties, etc.) which are not administered by the UN.

@ohwilleke, okay, thanks! Lots of good Answers here. I'll green-check this one as it seems to most directly answer the Question, though all of them contribute. The conclusion AFAICT is that there is no currently existing thing which could directly correspond to "UN law" as used in the fictional story; that, while there is precedent for such a thing happening, it would almost certainly be something new created for the specific situation. In particular, there is no basis to ask questions about this "UN law" without them being pure speculation.

@littleadv According to the Wikipedia article you linked, the Free City of Gdansk had its own Parliament and Senate. The League of Nations acted as a guarantor of its constitution and independence, and its relationship with Poland; but it didn't directly administer the territory. One of Wikipedia's references is a copy of its Constitution, which if I understand the translation correctly states that the initial body of law was inherited from Germany, not drafted by the League of Nations.

While not made by the UN, the Dayton Agreement was a treaty, and thus part of (public) international law, and it did contain the constitution of Bosnia Herzegovina as its annex.

When the UN administered Kosovo from 1999 to (de facto) 2008, Kosovo and all of its cities could technically be described as "under UN law." But this is misleading, because the UN expressly preserved all existing laws "insofar as they do not conflict with [international human rights standards and non-discrimination principles]." as described in this document. This was later amended to give full effect to Kosovo law as it was on March 22, 1989, but it was still subject to modifications by UN regulations and to international human rights standards.
At best, this was a mixture of UN law and Kosovo law, but in reality, I would tend to assume that UNMIK (the UN mission responsible for this work) tried to avoid directly legislating any more than absolutely necessary. As far as I can tell, they immediately worked to establish a democratic system of governance, holding local elections in 2000 and national elections the following year, as well as establishing an assembly (legislature) and other organs of democratic government. After that, the UN had at most a supervisory role in Kosovo's administration. Of course, that was the UN's plan all along - to establish a democratic government and then transfer most if not all of UNMIK's administrative responsibilities to that government.
This is illustrative of a broader point. The UN was not designed to function as a world government. While it does have the practical capacity to administer a territory for a time, this is an anomalous state of affairs. The immediate goal of any UN-administered territory with a non-trivial population will always be to establish, re-establish, or reinforce a democratic system of self-government and then transfer responsibilities into that government until the country is fully self-governing. A similar thing happened in Cambodia in 1992-93, and there have been a few other examples as well.
One or two of those examples don't fit this model, because they are essentially (or actually) demilitarized zones surrounded by some conflict, and will (presumably) be ceded to some country once the conflict no longer requires UN involvement (which may take a very long time to happen). It is difficult (and might be counterproductive) to set up a self-governing system for such a small territory, especially when that territory's ultimate fate may be at issue in the broader conflict. The end result is that these territories are under de facto martial law, but areas with more significant civilian population will usually be administered by one side or the other rather than by the UN. For example, as far as I can tell, both parts of Nicosia are administered by "regular" local governments, and it's just a thin strip of land that's officially UN-administered.

While there is currently no such thing as "UN Law" there are U.N. peacekeeping missions.
It isn't implausible that at some future date in a small geographic area, a U.N. peacekeeping mission could place a municipality under martial law, with the details of that martial law devised by the occupying peacekeeping mission military personnel, probably on the model of the laws in the countries of its senior officers.

The USA is famous for not subscribing to international agreements (https://www.hrw.org/news/2009/07/24/united-states-ratification-international-human-rights-treaties) presumably to protect its citizens overseas (my understanding). What laws are UN peacekeepers subject to within the confines say of a UN base?

@BuckThorn The local laws of the place, if there is one, and usually also the equivalent to the Uniform Code of Military Justice of the source country for the U.N. Peacekeeping troops. Thus, French peacekeeping troops in a U.N. Peacekeeping force would have to follow French military justice rules. The commanding officer of the peacekeeping mission could establish rules if there were multiple conflicting military justice requirements for the unit run by the C.O. usually with authority established in the documents establishing the peacekeeping mission.

The Vienna International Center in, unsurprising, Vienna, is an extraterritorial area with a complex set of legalities, including international laws and UN Treaties. In a sufficiently casual interpretation of the word, you could speak of "UN law" in this area.
Austrian law still applies to some degree, but the degree of extraterritoriality is strong enough that the UN has jurisdiction over its own staff and premises.
It is probably the real-world location closest to your scenario.

While the UN headquarters agreement with the US does not use the word "extraterritorial," that's more or less the only difference with the Vienna agreements.  The provisions in both places are essentially the same, including a provision that local (Austrian and New York) law applies in the UN area.

The Law (capital "L") requires a social contract to be established and upheld to be valid (otherwise it is not different from a dictatorship or other tyrant).  This social contract is the tacit agreement between the People and the governing body about how they are giving away some of their freedoms in order to establish their government and the law, in return.
A UN law (note small case) is not equivalent to "international law" because citizens of the world have not come together to establish a social contract to form an international government to make such laws valid and enforceable. As such, the UN is better seen, legally, as an international "corporation", rather than a government.
Even UN Laws could be challenged or refused by its member nations, but to where will you go without a true international government established by the social contract (rather than a mere signature of an elected leader to become a member of the UN)?
The dictums of American government apply to it`s citizens who are under the social contract that was effectively made back in 1700s (through several historical mechanisms), but cannot (ethically) and should not (legally) be used to grant powers upwards to establish greater authority than to what the citizens agreed.
